# How do i detect webrtc shapes and object position in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image-processing, computer-vision, webrtc, jsfeat

I am looking to valide when an object is being held close enough to the camera in webrtc and thought that I might detect a shape and compare the bounds to the size of the stream. It seemed like a simple enough task but I am having trouble detecting shapes with javascript. There are lots of examples of detecting faces or parts of faces with Haar cascades, but I am not sure if that is really what I should be looking for. The end goal would be to have something similar to banking apps that take a picture of a check once it's lined up or taking enough space in the stream. I am looking to just let the user know that that they have the item they will be taking a picture of centered and close enough to the camera. I have been looking at jsFeat which seems pretty cool and works well with predefined cascades such as faces, but how do i detect shapes or atleast the positioning of the main item in a video stream, without training my own cascades?

Comment: Currently I just have some svg guide overlays to help users but would like them to like turn green or something when they have their item in a good position.

Comment: not quite sure if I am ready for this: http://cdn.intechweb.org/pdfs/5781.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Wow, shape recognition in a video stream, sounds like a challenge, and will need a powerful processor. These links may steer you in the right direction.

The first is titled "**Object Detection with HTML5 getUserMedia**", and is a discussion on face recognition using javascript, and provides a bunch of links to projects

http://techslides.com/object-detection-with-html5-getusermedia

The second is tracking.js

> The tracking.js library brings different computer vision algorithms
>   and techniques into the browser environment. By using modern HTML5
>   specifications, we enable you to do real-time color tracking, face
>   detection and much more — all that with a lightweight core (~7 KB) and
>   intuitive interface

https://trackingjs.com/

Have fun, it sounds like a cool project!